# Как можно сделать доступ к файлам с моего сервера и все

Tags: php, javascript, веб-программирование, безопасность

День добрый. Есть ли возможность сделать так, что бы мои файлы mp3 мог проигрывать только с моего сайта, а другие решившие загрузить(проигрывать на других сайтах) файлы получили в ответ нет такого файла или что-то подобное. Плеер на javascript. Желательно пример с кодом. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: на стороне сервера вы можете смотреть referer.

Comment: да, но его могут подделывать в приложение(

Comment: но вы же сказали, что "решили загрузить на другом сайте". честные браузеры его подделывать не будут. А если вам надо что бы и спец программы, которые подделывать будут не могли то тогда отдавать динамические ссылки, которые генерит ваш сайт с ограниченным сроком действия и например с привязкой к кукам сессии пользователя/ip

Comment: Всё могут подделывать в приложении, так что, что если рассматривать ситуацию за пределами браузера, это невозможно.